# Bluestacks - Start & Exit application using Macro

Tags: macros, bluestacks

I have recorded a Bluestacks macro to perform menial tasks in the ZDay : Hearts for heros game.  However, because there are so many unpredictable popups in the application I would like the macro to start the app, run the menial activity I recorded and then exit the application.

The application doesn't have a specific way to exit (file/exit doesn't exist) except on the phone is to force it closed using the OS.  Is there a command I can put at the beginning of the macro to start the application and another to close the application at the end of the macro?

Answer (score 0):

Bluestacks has controls that allow perform a generic exit command.  So, I didn't need to know how to exit the program from inside the application.  I just used the built in functionality to accomplish what I need.